# How to create custom charts in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm willing to create a custom linear chart in android using XML and java. Anyone can help me to find a resource for this. I've tried the MPA Chart library but can't get the exact same result.

[image: Picture for reference]

Thanks.

Comment: If you have no problem going with libraries then look at [AnyChart](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android). I'm not promoting it, I just use it so I know it can.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to create a full custom chart. And I found a resource also.

Comment: What customization do you think you need? Because as I use it, I know it can be customized, you can check their example for that. But if you want to customize the whole layout which is definitely a limit with these libraries, you've to go with Bezier Curves. For that, you can understand the logic behind generating Line graphs from any open source library out there and then implement it. You should also implement Anychart's example first, it will also give you ideas to improve your own, its graphs are not just images, you can interact with them as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'll learn Bezier Curves.